# Execute a jar file ever Windows initialize and after the user logon (Not as a Service) that call a process with a GUI

Tags: java, windows

I have a jar file and I wanted to run this file as a service. When this .jar executes, it opens another program that I want to be able to see it GUI. But note: only the second program needs a GUI (the .jar not). I open this second program using the following:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdCommand);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Searching about this issue I saw that if I performed my .jar file as a service, I could not see the process started GUI because services executing in another desktop since Windows Vista. To create a service, I used Java Service Wrapper. On [this tutorial](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html), they teach how to use the wrapper.ntservice.interactive configuration to make for the service to display a GUI. They alert too:

"*Starting with Windows Vista and Server 2008, Microsoft changed the way services are allowed to interact with the desktop. They decided that for security reasons, services are now only allowed to show their GUI on a special desktop that only the service can interact with. Unfortunately, this makes interactive features pretty much useless. We are looking into ways to display a GUI in a different way. Stay tuned.
If you do a search on the Internet with keywords of "Interactive services dialog Vista", you will find a number of references to the way Windows will display a dialog on the user desktop whenever a service has updated into GUI on the services desktop.
There are some important security reasons why this was disabled in Windows. But if you really need to reenable this functionality, it is possible to do so by editing the Windows Registry and setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\NoInteractiveServices to 0. Always be very careful editing the registry as you can easily mess up your system by changing the wrong values.*"

I've been tried to configuration the NoInteractiveServices to 0, but yet do not work.

So, how can I execute a .jar program when windows initialize and the user do the login, and still be able to see the GUI of my opened process?

Comment: So what should it do if Windows has started but no one is logging on?

Comment: I will improve my issue. I need to start after the user login.

Comment: Then it's a completely different problem - not "start something on Windows startup", but "start something on user logon". Either list it in the registry undert `Run`. or under Programs\Startup on the Start menu. No GUI limitations there.

Comment: Do you still want to run the JAR as a service? Is that because you want it to run all the time, or do you want it to start when Windows starts?

Comment: I need to show a GUI interface and ensure that if the computer restarts, I will be able to reopen the GUI without needs a user around. This is the motivation of the service approach. But I saw that a GUI can be showed only for a user, and service is in another level.

Comment: Exactly; Windows only allows GUI in the context of a logged on user. What are you trying to do in the first place? This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: I need open a GUI and maintaining this GUI opened, independently of an eventual OS restart. I did a java program to manage the GUI opening.  I created a .bat file to run my java program. Finally, I did your tip, putting this on the Start menu. That solved a part of my problem. As for the eventual OS restart, I used the autologon program. I gave the problem as solved, but if you know a more appropriate way, I could try.

Comment: What's the purpose of the GUI?

Comment: The user uses this GUI to maintain a certain data production established. As I can't help using this GUI, I had to deal with it. After your tip, I even imagined that I could put the GUI itself inside the startup folder. But my program also records the status of this GUI in a database.

Comment: Two comments above you're saying the GUI doesn't need a user (apparently it needs to start even if there's no user at the computer). Now you're saying the GUI needs the user to do something. This is confusing.

Comment: When I say that the user uses this GUI to maintain some data production, I meant that the GUI must always be active so that the data is generated and the user (person) can get it at some point. Perhaps this is the confusion. I need to keep the GUI open at all times, even with a possible restart of the OS. I need a user (account) to be able to view this GUI. A user (person) will not be present to make sure that the GUI is running.

Comment: Does the GUI take any user input? Or is it a GUI that passively watches user activity?

Comment: The GUI takes user input, but once time per a long period to do some configuration and some analysis of data collected.